# Is there any other control like ListView in win32 or if there is any way to remove the title area of the ListView control which is available in win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there any other control like ListView in win32 or if there is any way to remove the title area of the ListView control which is available in win32. And can this be used for text formatting like tabs and bold, italics.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry i wanted to say Column header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want text-like features then use [rich edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to show list view control in report view without header then include [`LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style when creating the control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah i want to display some kind of report but still i want to know that is there formatting support for this control because the data that I am getting to display have tabs in it. Thanks once again

Comment: @user2829058 If you want more than just a table of data then rich edit control is the answer. It has [tabs (PFM_TABSTOPS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh768373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and many other nice features that you can use.

Comment: I dont want to use edit control because the data that i need to display have to be scrolled and rows must be clickable. and i am using some buttons to navigate in this listview. thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, the column header doesn't have to be visible at all. It can format each item individually too like bold, but tabs are best implemented as columns (without the header visible of course).

Without knowing more what you want, its difficult to advise.

Comment: I have data coming from some array of character and the first row defines the width of the comulns and the alignment of the text in the listview and data starts from the second row from that array that needs to follow all those formatting rules that have been laid down in the first row. thanks